# Using methods with reflection c#

Tags: c#, reflection

im trying to make an implementacion of a dictionary that goes `Dictionary<string, Func<string[], string>>` with reflection. As of right now i got it working like this

```
        lCommands.Add(new string[] { "help", "ayuda" }, HelpFunc);
        lCommands.Add(new string[] { "cambiacargo", "ccl" }, CambiarCargoLegislador);
        lCommands.Add(new string[] { "buscar" }, ObtenerDatosLegislador);
        lCommands.Add(new string[] { "listartiemposbloques" }, ObtenerTiemposBloques);
        lCommands.Add(new string[] { "modificartiemposbloques" }, ModificarTiempoBloque);
        lCommands.Add(new string[] { "logout" }, logout);
        lCommands.Add(new string[] { "tienepalabra", "hablado" }, TiempoPalabraActivo);
```

where the .Add is an extension method that takes an array of string, and a Func and make it keys for the same Func. My problem actually is that i would like to be able to this with reflection. So after searching for a while I ve been able to come up with this

```
   foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in typeof(CommandHelper).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static))
    {
        string methodName = methodInfo.Name;

        object[] attribute = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Command), true);

        if (attribute.Length > 0)
        {
            Command myAliases = (Command)attribute[0];

            lCommands.Add(myAliases.alias, /* here is my problem propertyInfo.Name*/);
        }
    }
```

but im not sure how to transform the methodInfo into a `Func<string[],string>`. To sum it up, i want to do the same for the first chunk of code with reflection

Just in case someone need it this is an example of one of the functions

```
    [Help(Remainder = "Obtiene el tiempo hablado por un legislador")]
    [Command("tienepalabra,hablado,tpa")]
    private static string TiempoPalabraActivo(string[] arg)
    {
        LegisladorService leServ = new LegisladorService();
        try
        {
            return $"el legislador {leServ.TraerPorIdNombreApellido(Form1._server.tienePalabra)} estuvo hablando durante {Form1._server.TiempoPalabra()}";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "No hay legislador con palabra activo";
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `.Invoke`  on the method info to execute the method.

This can be wrapped into a Func:

```
Func<string[],string> func = (parameters) => methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { parameters });
```

Comment: this is not working, i forgot to mention this is static, but even with methodInfo.invoke(null, parameters) its still saying i cannot use lambda function with an implicit type

Comment: Sorry. Forgot that lambdas cannot assigned to var.

Comment: Yeah i thought to do that, but the dictionary remains empty whenever i call one of the keys it does nothing :/. Although i dont have an obj since its a static method

Comment: To use null as a first parameter for a static class is correct.

Comment: yeah now its working although i hit a wall when parameters are null, any ideas i got this code 
                        Func<string[], string> func = (parameters) =>
                     {
                         try
                         {
                             return (string)methodInfo.Invoke(null, parameters);
                         }
                         catch (ArgumentException)
                         {

                             return (string)methodInfo.Invoke(null, null);
                         }

                     };

Comment: When calling invoke parameters has to always be an array. So you actually need an array in an array. I updated the answer